# PDFBox 2.0.9 - pdf to image with alpha

Tags: java, image, png, pdfbox

I have problem with transferring PDF page to image (png) using PDFBox. I'm trying to transfer to image because then I want to use in PowerPoint presentation. Everything works fine except one case. Graph colors are not passed to image when fill of graph has transparency setup and colors are not from main palette.
[Here is the link to pdf](https://easyupload.io/wwnxx9)

[Attaching sample image with pdf on left and output on the right](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OxEcY.png)

Here is sample responsible for pdf to img:

```
public static BufferedImage convertPDF2Image(PDDocument pdf, int page) throws IOException {
        BufferedImage image = null;
        ImageType imageType = ImageType.ARGB;
        // int dpi = 96;
        int dpi = 100;

        PDFRenderer renderer = new PDFRenderer(pdf);
        image = renderer.renderImageWithDPI(page, dpi, imageType);

        return image;
    }
```

Comment: Please retry with the current version (2.0.24) or is there something special with 2.0.9 that isn't in later versions? Also share the PDF.

Comment: Thanks for reply. 2.0.24 has same experience. I shared sample pdf i case description.

Comment: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PDFBOX-5251 created. PDF.js has the same problem. I'm pessimistic about this one :-(

Comment: If you created this file, can you create a simpler file (that only has that rectangle) that also brings this issue?

Comment: Same behaviour @TilmanHausherr.

Comment: Please share that file. Either here or in the JIRA ticket.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr, Here's a link to [pdf file with one graph](https://easyupload.io/t4sgya).